# Card Sorting to determine the correct term

Tags: card-sorting

I understand the premise of card sorting and its benefit.

My question, how do you use card sorting to determine the correct term that we want to use on the site.

For example under Media we can have **Video** or **Films** or **Movies** - these are all good terms, how do I use card sorting to find out which is the best?

Answer (score 5):

From [Card sorting: a definitive guide](http://www.boxesandarrows.com/view/card_sorting_a_definitive_guide):

> There are two primary methods for performing card sorts.
>
> - Open Card Sorting: Participants are given cards showing site content    with no pre-established groupings. They are asked to sort
>   cards into    groups that they feel are appropriate and then describe
>   each group.    Open card sorting is useful as input to information
>   structures in new    or existing sites and products.
> - Closed Card Sorting: Participants are    given cards showing site content with an established initial set of    primary groups.
>   Participants are asked to place cards into these    pre-established
>   primary groups. Closed card sorting is useful when    adding new
>   content to an existing structure, or for gaining    additional
>   feedback after an open card sort.

So, you should use open card sorting.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly the grouping isn't what you are concerned with. In other words, you aren't trying to identify what group to put "Video" or "Films" or "Movies" into as you already have that defined (i.e. "Media"). Instead you are interested in what to label the individual items. If that's the case then I don't believe a card sort is the technique you should be using.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the appropriate term is brought about by deliberation within the participants and building a consensus.
If there is still ambiguity then I would propose to go in for -

1. Forced ranking method - where ranks are made for each items and they are added up across, say 4 participants rank an item A: 1+2+3+4 = 10 (the minimal number in the gross seems to be the most agreed term - since 1+1+2+2 = 6 is mostly top with the priority
2. Dot voting method - Ask participants to vote for the each of the item (Give 5 votes for each participant) and ask them to vote on the terms.

If in case you want to divulge from these methods, do usability testing with these terms with a fresh set of participants or colleagues. This could be informal and could provide lots of insight.